# Target not destroying or subtracting 10 from its health

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was programming when I came across a problem where the health of the enemy would not drop down let alone destroying the gameObject.

Here is the code to both of the scripts:

Script 1

```
using UnityEngine;

public class target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;

    public void takeDamage(float amount)
    {
        amount -= health;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

script 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera fpsCam;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.takeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's supposed to happen is the target object is supposed to destroy the object when it hits 0 health.

Please, help me

Comment: Is the takeDamage function called normal?

Comment: `amount -= health` subtracts from `amount` not from `health`. Swap the operands around. It should be `health -= amount`, the left hand operand is the one that is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You have your operands mixed up.

The left hand operand is the one that is assigned to.

```
amount -= health;
```

Will assign a result to `amount` not to `health`.

Swap the operands around:

```
health -= amount;
```

Assignment is always on the left side.

All that's happening at the moment is that your passed in amount is having the health subtracted from it and then discarded.